# scanf and getchar together to read string

Tags: c, string, scanf, getchar

I have this code:

```
Hotel new_h = (Hotel*)malloc(sizeof(Hotel));
printf("\nInsert name -> ");
scanf("%[^\n]s", new_h->name);
getchar();
```

First of all, how it works %[^\n]s

Why there isn't just %s inside scanf?

And why there is getchar too?

Comment: This document: http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html will explain you the `%[^\n]s` syntax.

Comment: The `getchar()` is here to consume the remaining `\n` from `stdin`

Comment: In short: with `%[^\n]s` syntax, your hotel name can have spaces.

Comment: I think it also works with `scanf("%[^\n]", new_h->name);`.

Comment: BTW: `"%[^\n]s"` should be `"%[^\n]"` There's no need for an `s` on the end. The `[^\n]` is not a qualifier for a `%s` conversion. It is a conversion in and of itself.

Comment: Post the definition of `Hotel`. If `h->name` is not an array, the code will have undefined behavior.

Comment: @user3386109 `"%[^\n]"` is as bad as `gets()`.

Comment: @chux `%s` is as bad as `gets()` too.

Answer (score 0):

The `getchar()` function in this case would only be necessary if you were to do a following input after the hotel name, in wich case I would recommend you to just add a space before %s, something like this `scanf(" %[^\n]s", new_h->name);`.

Regarding that `malloc()` how's your definition of hotel because it has to be declared as a pointer, so you're able to allocate memory to it casting it to type pointer isn't enough and it will leed to a segfault you should declare it as

```
Hotel *new_h = malloc(sizeof(Hotel));
```

This is considering that you are defining hotel as something like this

```
typedef struct{
    //Some vars
}Hotel;
```

Comment: The `s` in `" %[^\n]s"` serves no purpose.

Comment: surprisingly it doesn't do much harm either :D

Comment: @AnttiHaapala A better use of  `"%[^\n]"` uses a width like `"%99[^\n]"`.  In that better use case, the `s` in  `"%99[^\n]s"`  can do harm.

Comment: True dat too :D